# AJAX call terminates abruptly sometimes with empty status code and response and response header in ios

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

Problem - We are building a hybrid app using apache cordova.We initiate an ajax call during app launch.Out of 200 times 3/4 times , the call fails and gets terminated without any error status code or response or response header.While debugging in mac we can see it in console, the ajax call is initiated,but it failed with a "- " status code in console.Along with that,from logs we can see that it never reached the server.

OS affected :IOS 9 and above versions alone.
jQuery version - 1.10.2
Apache cordova js file version
IOS -3.8.0
Android -5.1.0

Issue with ios only though.

Any help will be much appreciated.Any other details requested please ask.Will update the post accordingly.

Update 1 - Can't change jQuery version and cordova version to higher versions,client is not agreeing with the regression testing scope and time that will take once the version update is made along with any change in plugin versions itself.

Update 2- updated cordova min js version now we are using.issue is still there for ios though.

Comment: You are using old cordova (and old jQuery). Use at least cordova 5.xx.

Comment: I know but can't change them, client is not agreeing at all no matter how hard we try .Will try again today.But hope is very less that way.:(

Comment: Your client has no choice. Cordova 4 is old and not supported anymore and it has security vulnerabilities. For example, starting last month (i.e. May), Google Play (i.e. Android) will not accept any Cordova 4 apps (new or updates). Apple is still accepting it, but they will stop sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks for the info.will check on this.apart from the old plugins angle,any suggestions on why this may occur that too only in ios 9 and above and so infrequently.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code. From your description, it's likely to be the execution order of different parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this plugin https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP.
Check if this plugin is supported for cordova 4.

and then try making a ajax call with cordovaHTTP.post